# CakePHP AssetCompress: Not generating compressed files in cache folders

Tags: javascript, cakephp, plugins, compression, assets

Has anyone here used Mark Story's Asset Compress (https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress/) plugin ?

I've followed the installation instructions to the last bit and have the plugin up and running - but it simply won't generate the combined JS files to the specified cache (cache_js) folder.

I'm using Cake 1.3 and v0.2 of AssetCompress (the latest available download from github).

1. The plugin has been placed in the app/plugins/asset_compress folder
2. Cache folders - cache_js and cache_css created in WEBROOT
3. JsMin and CssMin filters downloaded and added to app/vendors/JsMin and app/vendors/CssMin respectively
4. Config file setup to point to the cache folders and filters
5. Routes configured as per requirements
6. Debug mode set to 1

My **config.ini**:

```
[Javascript]
searchPaths[] = WEBROOT/js/
searchPaths[] = WEBROOT/js/jquery/
searchPaths[] = WEBROOT/js/jquery/plugins/
stripComments = true
cacheFilePath = WEBROOT/cache_js/
cacheFiles = false
filters[] = JsMin

[Css]
searchPaths[] = WEBROOT/css/
stripComments = true
cacheFilePath = WEBROOT/cache_css/
cacheFiles = false
filters[] = CssMin
```

Still no output in the cache folders.

Any ideas why ?

Thanks,
m^e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work.

Turns out I was messing around with v0.2 which is what you get by default when you hit the DOWNLOAD button at the **[GitHub repository of Asset Compress](https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress)**.

You've to check out the latest version from GitHub using a git client like **[msysGit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/)** (if you are on Windows) and then be extra careful about where you are placing the asset inclusion commands.

Here are the steps you need to take:

1. Place the contents of the download in a folder named **asset_compress** under your app's plugins folder.
2. Include the plugin as a helper (preferably in your app_controller.php)

   **public $helpers = array(
       'AssetCompress.AssetCompress',
   );**
3. In your layout file, place the asset inclusion commands, e.g.

   **$this->AssetCompress->script( filename );**
4. Just before the point where you place echo $scripts_for_layout in your layout, place the statement,

   **echo $this->AssetCompress->includeJs();**

...and you're good to go.

Cheers,
m^e

Answer (score 0):

I did not use this plugin yet
but just few comments.
-sometimes minification leads to the hells (javascript errors)especially if you mimnify an already minified version
-minification makes comments and license agreements disappear which makes things illegal.

I personally, do not prefer to compress assets using plugins.
**plugin in cakePHP by definition is a semi application not just a utility class** (helper, component, behavior, or any vendor utility class)
currently I am compressing the concatenated javascript files (resp css files) in the AppController by using just one function

Comment: Thanks for your reply - but Assetcompress seems to do a terrific job.. even when there are packed files present.